# Flutter Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer() doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer

I want to open a drawer after pushing on the custom button in BottomMenu I have  trouble with Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(), it doesn't work. My BottomMenu  is a **separate** widget class. As I understand, it doesn't work because it's a separate context. How can I get the right context? Or perhaps someone knows another solution.

Here my code reproducer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Drawer'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomMenu(),
      endDrawer: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Drawer(
          elevation: 16,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                    title: Text('Some context here',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                ListTile(
                    title: Text('Some context here',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Call Drawer form menu reproducer',
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
      child: Wrap(
        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Divider(color: Colors.black, height: 1),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
            child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  InkWell(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    customBorder: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 3, right: 6, bottom: 15, top: 11),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.menu),
                          Text('Show menu', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer()
```

Answer (score 19):

In my case, this worked.

```
return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      endDrawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false,  // This!
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu, size: 36),
          onPressed: () => _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),  // And this!
        ),
      ),
      drawer: DrawerHome(),
      ....
```

and `_scaffoldKey` must be initialized as,

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

under the class.

Comment: I tried this solution but **without** adding `endDrawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false,` and it still worked.. :)

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you specified `endDrawer` on `Scaffold` yet you're calling `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()`.

[`openDrawer()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/openDrawer.html) documentation states:

> If the scaffold has a non-null Scaffold.drawer, this function will cause the drawer to begin its entrance animation.

Since your `drawer` is null, nothing happens.

In contrast, [`openEndDrawer()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/openEndDrawer.html) informs us:

> If the scaffold has a non-null Scaffold.endDrawer, this function will cause the end side drawer to begin its entrance animation.

Since your `endDrawer` is not null you should use `openEndDrawer()` method. Alternatively, if you don't care which side the drawer slides in from, you can use `drawer` instead of `endDrawer` when building `Scaffold`.

Answer (score 8):

My problem solved that instead of

```
Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer()
```

I give key to Scaffold and then I call by state like below

```
_scaffoldkey.currentState.openEndDrawer()
```

It solved my problem I hope It also works for you

Answer (score 4):

**The Problem**

This issue can occur when you do not use the correct `BuildContext` when calling `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()` (or `openEndDrawer()`).

**Easiest Solution**

Simply wrap whatever calls `openDrawer()` (or `openEndDrawer()`) with a `Builder` widget. This will give it a working `context`.

**Minimal Working Example**

```
// your build method
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: Builder(builder: (context) { // this uses the new context to open the drawer properly provided by the Builder
      return FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (() => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer())); 
    }),
    drawer: const Drawer(
      child: Text("MY DRAWER"),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem here. Clicked on button and nothing happened. The problem is I was using the context of the widget that instantiated Scaffold. Not the context of a child of Scaffold.

Here is how I solved it:

```
// body: Column(
        //   children: <Widget>[
        //     Row(
        //       children: <Widget>[        
        //         IconButton(
        //           icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
        //           onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(), (wrong context)
        //         ),
        //       ],
        //     ),
        //   ],
        // )
```

To:

```
body: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
                          onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

you need wrap Builder, like this:

```
AppBar(
                leading: Builder(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.abc_outlined),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                      },
                    );
                  }
                ),
//...//
```

Its working for me!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assign Drawer to drawer property in scaffold. Wrap your specific Widget/Button(where you want to open drawer on its click method) with Builder. Use below method on click property:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mScVz.png)
Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Try to [edit] your answer and copy-paste it in between \`\`\` the code \`\`\`.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** ANY OTHER TYPE OF BUTTON WON'T WORK FOR INVOKING THE DRAWER

Must use **IconButton**

**Example:**

```
AppBar(leading: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return IconButton(
            icon:Text("Open Drawer"), // icon property is of type Widget
            onPressed: () {
              Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
            },
          );
        }))
```

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('This is the body of the app.'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomMenu(scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey),
    );
  }
}

class BottomMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;

  const BottomMenu({Key? key, required this.scaffoldKey}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          label: 'Settings',
        ),
      ],
      onTap: (index) {
        // Open the drawer when the settings button is tapped.
        if (index == 1) {
          scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this and worked

```
Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you have the appbar widget with an action button to launch the drawer and the drawer is never pushed please remember that you need to define after `appbar: ...` the          `endDrawer: YOURAppDrawerWIDGET(),` or else using the `Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer()` will not work.

```dart
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text(_title)),
    endDrawer: AppDrawer(), // <-- this is required or else it will not know what is opening
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
     ///...
```